# Making breakout game

Tags: c#, algorithm

My friends I made some parts of this game but I have two problems in this game.

1)Problem about distinguishing ball collision with obstacles

1-1)A first problem is related to complex guidelines that I used them for simulation of ball collision with board or ball collision with blocks. These guidelines are not accurate especially when the ball meets with block corner or bottom.
If it is not better for collision distinguish I use a better code. I wrote this code. Are you think that are there better way?

2)How I can do a work that if the ball collision with any obstacle, the obstacle report the collision.

My aim is about using of events.
Are you thinking that I make obstacles as runtime?
If I make as a runtime, how I can make collision event for them?

With best regards

```
  private Point MouseDownLocation;

    int step = 2;
    int stepleft = 2;


    bool flagBottom;
    bool flagTop;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Interval = 10;
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ball.Top += step;
        ball.Left += stepleft;

        //board simulate collision
        bool collisonX = ball.Location.X + ball.Width > board.Location.X && ball.Location.X < board.Location.X + board.Width;
        bool collisonY = ball.Top + ball.Height == board.Location.Y || ball.Top + ball.Height - 1 == board.Location.Y;

        //board2(button1) simulate collision
        bool collisonX2 = ball.Location.X + ball.Width > board2.Location.X && ball.Location.X < board2.Location.X + board2.Width;
        bool collisonY2 = ball.Top + ball.Height == board2.Location.Y || ball.Top + ball.Height - 1 == board2.Location.Y;

        //Collision the ball with under buttons 
        bool collsionButtonY = ball.Top - ball.Height == board2.Location.Y || ball.Top - ball.Height == board2.Location.Y - 1;

        //collision leftwall 
        bool leftWall = ball.Left == 0 || ball.Left == -1 || ball.Left == 1;
        //collision rightwall 
        bool topWall = ball.Top == 0 || ball.Top == -1 || ball.Top == 1;

        bool bottomWall = collisonX && collisonY;
        bool toppWall = collisonX2 && collisonY2;

        //collision 
        bool barrier = collisonX2 && collsionButtonY;

        //rightwall
        bool rightWall = ball.Left + ball.Width == this.ClientSize.Width || ball.Left + ball.Width == this.ClientSize.Width - 1;
        // sidewall = collision rightwall or leftwall 
        bool sideWall = leftWall || rightWall;

        //Check the ball hit the ground 
        bool check = ball.Top + ball.Height < this.ClientSize.Height;


        //if topWall true,This means that the ball is hit to the topwall

        if (topWall)
        {
            flagBottom = false;
            flagTop = true;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                step = 2;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                step = 2;
            }



        }
        //if bottomWall true,This means that the ball is hit to the board

        else if (bottomWall)
        {
            flagBottom = true;
            flagTop = false;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;

            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {

                step = step * -1;
            }


        }
        //if barrier true and flagbottom true,This means that the ball is hit to the board2(button1)

        else if (barrier && flagBottom)
        {

            if (stepleft > 0)
            {

                step = step * -1;

            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;

            }
        }
        //if toppWall true and flagTop true,This means that the ball is hit to The top button is hit 

        else if (toppWall && flagTop)
        {
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;

            }
        }
        else if (sideWall)
        {
            //if leftwall true,This means that the ball is hit to the left side wall
            if (leftWall)
            {
                if (flagTop)
                {
                    stepleft = 2;
                }
                else if (flagBottom)
                {

                    stepleft = 2;
                }
            }
            //if rightWall true,This means that the ball is hit to the left side wall
            else if (rightWall)
            {
                if (flagTop)
                {
                    stepleft = -2;
                }
                else if (flagBottom)
                {
                    stepleft = -2;
                }

            }


        }
            //check if ckeck==ture,this mean the ball is hit the ground
        else if (!check)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }





    }
  private void board_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }

    }

    private void board_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            board.Left = e.X + board.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define each "Wall" as an Object, this will increase your codes readablility. it will also allow you to define an Event for each wall, Listen to t. that way you know which wall has been hit

N.b. this is pseudo code. It wont compile :P

```
public class Wall
{
    int X,Y,W,H;

    //Define an event, add a listener to this, becuase we will fire this when there is a collision
    public event EventHandler OnCollision;


    public void CollisionCheck(Ball playerBall)
    {
       //1 Check for a collision with the "Ball" object
       if(Ball.Rectangle().Intersects(this.Rectangle))
         this.OnCollision(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Fire the event, null check might be requried

    }
}
```

Comment: It was a good idea for walls, 
But what about what are the obstacles(board2 or button1)? 
How do I use events for obstacles?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your game but (suspect 2D brick-like game)

1. Objects/Obstacles

   - all objects/obstacles can be simplified to rectangular objects
   - so make list of them with defined parameters like size and position
   - if they are movable/dropable then also speed and state...
   - type of object (affects color,scoring,capabilities...)
   - create member function like update(dt),draw()
   - create events you like OnHIt,OnCollision,...

for example (C++ pseudo code):

```
// game object types ...
enum _game_object_type_enum
 {
 _game_object_type_none=0,
 _game_object_type_wall,
 _game_object_type_brick1,
 _game_object_type_brick2,
 _game_object_type_brick3,
 _game_object_type_bomb,
 _game_object_type_joker1,
 _game_object_type_joker2,
 ...
 };

// game object class
class game_object
 {
public;
 int type;                // type of object  
 float x,y,vx,vy,hx,hy; // position,speed,half size of rectangle
 void update(float dt); // this call periodicaly in some timer updates positions,... and call events, dt is time passed
 void draw(); // can add some rendering device context ...
 };

// whole game class holds the game world/board/map and player(s) ...
class game_board
 {
public;
 game_object *go; int gos; // list of all objects in game
 void update(float dt) { for (int i=0;i<gos;i++) go[i].update(dt); }
 void draw() { for (int i=0;i<gos;i++) go[i].draw(); }
 }
```

2. events and flow control

   - first define some events you need
   - either you use global function/pointers for that or as members
   - depends on your platform and to what you are used to

for example like this:

```
void OnCollisionFX(game_object o1,game_object o2)
 {
 // do something ...
 }

void (*OnCollision)(game_object o1,game_object o2)=OnCollisionFX;
```

- for player interactions only (like player controlled object collisions test only)
- is better to handle this in `game_object::update(dt)` but you need to add player context
- something like  `game_object::update(dt,plr)`
- where `plr` is pointer to player controlled object or player class
- if you have massive interactivity between game objects (like brick/brick collisions)
- then is better to handle this in `game_board::update(dt)`
- because otherwise you will need to provide references for everything into update call
- and that will quickly lead to heap/stack trashing and very slow performance
- also more advanced multiple object collision/interaction approaches are better in main game class

here is an example for first case:

```
void game_object::update(float dt,game_object &plr)
 {
 // update position
 x+=vx*dt;
 y+=vy*dt;  

 // here you should make your own collision test of coarse
 if (fabs(x-plr.x)<=hx+plr.hx) 
  if (fabs(y-plr.y)<=hy+plr.hy) 
  {
  ... do what you need like mirror or stop speed or clamp position ...
  if (OnCollision) OnCollision(this,plr);
  }

 }
```

in second case you should check each object against each other

```
void game_board::update(float dt)
 {
 int i,j;
 // update position
 for (i=0;i<gos;i++)
  {
  go[i].x+=go[i].vx*dt;
  go[i].y+=go[i].vy*dt;
  }

 // here you should make your own collision test of coarse
 for (i=0;i<gos;i++)
  for (j=i+1;j<gos;j++) // the lower indexes are already tested
   if (fabs(go[i].x-go[j].x)<=go[i].hx+go[j].hx) 
    if (fabs(go[i].y-go[j].y)<=go[i].hy+go[j].hy) 
  {
  ... do what you need like mirror or stop speed or clamp position ...
  if (OnCollision) OnCollision(go[i],go[j]);
  }

 }
```

3. performance

   - you can improve performance by use of type property
   - for example if some game objets are static then the do not need to update position
   - if some are indestructible then there can be also some processing avoided and so on ...

[notes]

- dt/fps/speed should be combined
- so in each frame your player controlled object or any moving object does not move further
- then the half size of smallest object
- if this is not true then you need better collision test
- use line intersection algorithm
- last position and actual position gives you one line
- and object edge gives you the other one
- if booth objects are moving then that is even more complicated :)